# How can we write a BDD scenario fr complex flow

Tags: automation, bdd, gherkin, feature-file

How can we write a BDD scenario fr complex flow.

****For example:**** I want to write a scenario for creating a new user registration for wifi connection.

It will be one scenario where it will ask for customer details, product details , payment details, account details and at the end its creating a new account for the customer. How can we write a scenario to test this one scenario. 
we can write separate scenario for each module, but by combining this modules and cover as one flow is what needed. Please help me on this.

There can be other scenarios also like premium user, guest user, but this full flow will be one part.

Comment: what is your actual problem? what is stopping you just writing that scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best ways to write BDD for long stories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785073/best-ways-to-write-bdd-for-long-stories)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Cucumber?

You can do something like

```
Feature: Check user is registered for wifi
  Scenario: registration
    Given:
    When:
    Then: Account is created
```

And for the above steps you need to create a java step file which will contain you step definition.

```
@Then("^Account is created$")

public void accountCreated(){
 //do some validation
}
```